# Crear un menu circular en ios con swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito hacer un menú en `IOS`, que cuando arranque la aplicación salga un menú como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado mirando librerías pero ninguna se asemeja a lo que necesito.

He probado también con `constraints` pero no consigo que me quede parecido

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar esto? ¿Hay alguna librería o alguna clase propia de [swift](/questions/tagged/swift)?

Comment: Pues [aquí tienes](https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu) uno que a mi parecer hace exactamente lo que pides. Es muy bonito además. Solo tendrías que añadir las secciones que tu quieres y modificar algunas cositas para que fuera tu gusto. Ya me dirás si te sirve.

Answer (score 3):

podrías intentar haciéndolo manualmente y asignando cada item del menu por separado en la posición que desees

```
var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame.size.width = 50
    button.frame.size.height = 50
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
    button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    button.frame.origin.x = width / 2 - 25
    button.frame.origin.y = height / 2 - 25
    // -25 debido a que el punto de anclaje es el 0.0 del boton se le resta la mitad de su tamaño para que quede centrado en la pantalla
    view.addSubview(button)

    let button1 = UIButton()
    button1.frame.size.width = 50
    button1.frame.size.height = 50
    button1.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
    button1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    button1.frame.origin.x = width * 0.35 - 25
    button1.frame.origin.y = height * 0.35 - 25
    view.addSubview(button1)

    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.frame.size.width = 50
    button2.frame.size.height = 50
    button2.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
    button2.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    button2.frame.origin.x = width * 0.20 - 25
    button2.frame.origin.y = height * 0.5 - 25
    view.addSubview(button2)
```

[image: ejemplo de como luciría con los primeros 3 items]

Comment: esta bueno el circulo iluminati

Answer (score 2):

Creo que es posible de generar con la libería standard de aplicaciones UIKit, de todas maneras en caso que sea realmente compleja la animación podrías utilizar Sprite Kit : https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/

Te dejo un ejemplo que generé con UIKit estándar:

[image: En Xcode]

** Por puntaje de Stack no me deja subir mas imágenes, pero queda bien en el dispositivo.

Comment: Pero queda bien si se cambia de dispositivo?

Comment: Puedes dejar los botones amarrados al largo del view superior y luego ajusta con constraints a la disposición que gustes. Eso ya depende mucho del efecto que quieres lograr, si mantienes el tamaño y ajustas la posición. Ó si ajustas el tamaño y mantienes la posición etc, pero puedes manejarlo con el objeto superior.

Comment: Ejemplo si mantienes el tamaño se vería así en iphone 4 y en iPad Pro horizontal: http://imgur.com/a/KRW9m

Answer (score 2):

He estado buscando un poco sobre el tema y he encontrado unas cuantas librerías que podrían servirte de ayuda. A continuación te pongo las que he encontrado y creo que pueden serte de utilidad:

- [**ALRadialMenu**](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALRadialMenu) : Un menú radial / circular con animaciones de Spring. Está desarrollado en Swift.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- [**Circle Menu**](https://dribbble.com/shots/2534780-Circle-Menu-Swift-Open-Source) : Un menú radial / circular con animaciones. Se pueden personalizar el número de botones de 1 a 10, incluso más. Escrito en Swift.
- [**KYCircleMenu**](https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu) : Un menú circular con animación. Se pueden personalizar el número de botones entre 1 y 6. Escrito en Objective-C.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que alguno te sirva de ayuda.

Feliz Navidad!!!